# Number of groups with a certain property that that every element commutes with identity and itself only

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let  $S$  be  the  collection  of  groups (  isomorphism  classes) $G$  which  have  the  property  that  every  element  commutes  with  identity  and  itself  only .  Then  what  is  the  cardinality  of  $S$ ?

Apologies  people  ,  I  am  clueless  here.  Could  not  begin .

Comment: Do you know that every element commutes with its powers? What does that tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an element always commutes with its powers, we have that every element has order 2. In particular, this implies $a = a^{-1}$ for every $a \in G$. Also, a group with this property must be abelian, since $[a, b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1} = abab = (ab)^2 = e$.

Now, if the group has more than two elements, all these should commute, which contradicts the initial conditions. So, the group must have one or two elements and is isomorphic either to trivial group or $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 10):

We want every element to commute with only identity element and itself. If you have a group of order 2 then identity element in group commutes with other element, which is not allowed. So there is only one group with given condition which is $\{e\}$ where $e$ is identity. So there is only $1$ element in $S$.

Comment: This is an interesting take on the problem, the first time I've heard it argued this way. :) The problem might have been better posed if the condition "every element commutes with itself and identity only" was applied only to non-identity elements. Without that restriction, you've applied the redundancy of the condition on $e$ itself to argue that $S$ is the trivial group. Nice! +1

Comment: I'm really amazed with your answer . +1 really great